# Replace iframe App With Angular/React App

Tags: angular, reactjs, iframe, embed, web-component

My company (Child) currently has an application that is executed in another company's (Parent) website via an iframe and source link.  This Parent website has other pages and apps, but has one tab where our application runs.  The plan is to discontinue using the iframe/source-link method to render our web application.  Instead, we want to create our application using a more modern framework (Angular or React) and embed that application on their website in the tab they have for us, but NOT use the iframe.  This question may have been answered but I've had a hard time searching here and elsewhere for an answer that satisfies me.

What would be the proper method of handling this non-iframe way of embedding our application to our Parent's website, and what instructions would we need to provide to them and any other Parent company that wishes to use our new app in their website?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the way [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) manages displaying the react app in an HTML-document.

It basically replaces a simple element `<div id="root"/>` by the complete rendered React App. It would imply that this tag, together with JavaScript could should be sufficient for running the app in the parent website.

Hence, the `<iframe>` tag you want to get rid of is replaced by a single simple `<div>` tag.

Comment: This is how a React application can be rendered to a div tag, which I understand totally.  The issue is that the Parent website page has no current indication of React or Angular.  Their app takes this source link that our api system provides and embeds it into an iframe on their page.  We want to institute a process that wipes out the iframe, and in its place put a React/Angular SPA component that will grab the correct page/form to display based on what data the Parent website sends to it.